# Subversion - Add text file - File Status A (bin)

Tags: svn

I don't know why I'm getting (bin) in the file status - I checked the file and there are no special characters.  The add and commit worked and the file is probably fine, but I just thought it was odd.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#binary-files

> Subversion treats the following files as text:
>
> - Files with no svn:mime-type
> - Files with a svn:mime-type starting "text/"
> - Files with a svn:mime-type equal to "image/x-xbitmap"
> - Files with a svn:mime-type equal to "image/x-xpixmap"
>
> All other files are treated as binary, meaning that Subversion will:
>
> - Not attempt to automatically merge received changes with local changes during svn update or svn merge
> - Not show the differences as part of svn diff
> - Not show line-by-line attribution for svn blame

Check your file extension / associated mime type. You can force it to text by doing a propset on the the `svn:mime-type` to be different than the system's associated mime type.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I should get to read the faq more closely.  I checked the hex version and the file, which contains sql code, was saved as unicode by SSMS.

Comment: I had a similar problem with XML files: by default they're added as `(bin)` because if their `application/` MIME type.  After adding these files, I ran an explicit `svn propset svn:mime-type text/xml *` and it works just fine.  To make this easier, there's a helpful script here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/bin/set_svn_properties.sh