# What does '(bin)' indicate when adding files and then commiting in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have added some new files to my Rails project using 'svn add' command. After committing some of the files are having a status '(bin)'. What does that indicate?

My terminal window is shown below:

```
rahulv@PS386:~/sprint/S27$ svn commit -m "design fixes"
Adding  (bin)  app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png
Adding  (bin)  app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons_hidpi.png
Adding         app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/moono/images
Adding  (bin)  app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/moono/images/arrow.png
Adding  (bin)  app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/moono/images/close.png
Adding         app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/moono/images/hidpi
Transmitting file data ..........................
Committed revision 7.
rahulv@PS386:~/sprint/S27$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849239/subversion-add-text-file-file-status-a-bin).

It just means that this is a binary file (in your case an image) which will be handled differently than text files (for example text files you can update in svn versioning by applying deltas (only changes), but with images you can't).